# Django admin memory usage keeps increasing until runserver/process is killed

Tags: python, mysql, django, memory, django-admin

I am running a Django website with a small mysql database containing legal documents (<1000 rows, approx 74mb most of which will be the documents contents).

The views I wrote to display those rows and to edit documents work all fine both using the runserver in development and on production using mod_wsgi and apache.

However, the admin views to list these documents both in dev and prod cause memory use to go up incrementally on each page reload/refresh. I found that several of these document related list views show this behavior.

I just can seem to pinpoint what the root cause is. I am thinking along the lines of all records and related records being loaded in memory. But the list views don't display all that data.

The most simple admin view that shows the behavior is:

```
@admin.register(RegulationFile)
class RegulationFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """RegulationFile model admin class."""
    list_display = ("regulation", "imported_file")
```

Where regulation is the document and has a contents field that stores HTML. This html part can be fairly big, but I don't understand why it would disturb this admin view.

I tried changing the model admin to:

```
@admin.register(RegulationFile)
class RegulationFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """RegulationFile model admin class."""
    list_display = ("get_regulation_name", "imported_file")

    def get_regulation_name(self, obj):
        return obj.regulation.name
```

But that did not resolve the issue.

The memory increments are about 100mb each page reload. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Django 1.9.7 by the way.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear from your question what exactly is taking up the memory.  wsgi? apache? python? mysql?

Comment: On dev it is the runserver process that takes up the memory. On prod it is apache (mod_wsgi).